# Why is JOptionPane.showInputDialog is called more than it should, why and how to prevent it

Tags: java, joptionpane

I am trying to learn some basic java by following a book, one of the exercises requires that I display a set of bar graphics based on user input.

I have to query the user to input the no. of bars to be shown and the length of each.

I use the following:

1`st is the Bar class I defined to draw rectangles corresponding to the numbers inputed

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Bar extends JPanel
{
    private int noOfBars; // number of bars to display
    int i = 0;

// constructor with choice input
public Bar (int noOfBars)
{
    this.noOfBars = noOfBars;
}

// draw desired shapes starting from default position (0, 5) and incrementing for each new bar

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);


        do
        {
            String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number: ");
            int length = Integer.parseInt(input);

            for (int j = 1; j <= length; j++)
            g.drawRect(0, 5 + i * 20 ,j * 15 , 15);
            i++;

        }   while (i < noOfBars);

    }

}
```

2`nd is the main class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ShapesExercise
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    int noOfBars = 0;
    // obtain user choice



    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter total bars to display:");
    noOfBars = Integer.parseInt(input);

    if (noOfBars == 0)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid number.");
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter total bars to display::");
            noOfBars = Integer.parseInt(input);
        }

    JFrame application = new JFrame();
    application.setSize(300, 40 + 25 * noOfBars);
    Bar panel = new Bar(noOfBars);
    application.add(panel);
    application.setVisible(true);
    application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

My issue is as follows:
The first message_dialog (the one created in the main class) works correctly, popping up only once and querying for input.

But the message_dialogs generated by the Bar class keep popping up even after reaching the end of the "do while" loop (this was initially a "for" loop but I changed it to "do while" in an attempt to troubleshoot the code).

I have no idea why this happens. While researching online I could not find something related.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: why that happens? it doesn't, it can't. unless the code you've shown is not the code you compiled and are running

Comment: Hey Stultuske, the code I`ve shown is the code I ran.

Answer (score 2):

paintComponent is called by Swing’s painting architecture, which in turn is largely dependent on the native system.  paintComponent can be called several times per second, depending on the circumstances;  it may be called once, or several times, when a window is moved or brought to the front.  It may be called for each movement of the mouse over it.

You have no control over when paintComponent is called.  You must only draw in that method.  You *MUST NOT* call JOptionPane in it.  You must not change any state, and you must not change the component or any other components in that method.

If you want to call JOptionPane, do it elsewhere, and then call repaint() to request that the Swing system eventually call your paintComponent method.

You can learn more at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/.

Comment: Hey VGR, thank you for your feed-back. Taking into account your recommendations I`ve moved all JOptionPane Input Dialogue in my main method and it seems to have done the job.